# Best method for programmatically requesting db table columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there a good way of requesting only specified columns from the database using LINQ? I want to be able to select only certain columns depending on arbitrary conditions from code.

Comment: Came across this article, http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create anonymous types for each condition, which contain only the columns you specify.

```
var anonymousType = from item in itemCollection
   select new {Column1 = item.Column1, Column2 = item.Column2};

var anonymousType2 = from item in itemCollection
   select new {Column2 = item.Column2, Column3 = item.Column3};
```

Comment: so I have to create an anonymousType for each and every combination of columns that I have for each table?.. wow

Comment: I guess it all depends how complicated your implementation is.  Creating anonymous types from a query is the quick solution (the point of LINQ being to make these things easy and maintainable).  If you need a more complicated solution, the link you commented seems to do the trick. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean.

Are you maybe wanting to pull different columns based on a conditional?

Something like this?

```
if(condition)
{
    table.Select(x => x.ColumnA);
}
else
{
    table.Select(x => x.ColumnB);
}
```